# I am trying to assign the value of a variable to a 'data-index' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a "Computer Move" option for a Tic-Tac-Toe project. My game board grid consists of buttons with the same class (.box). I am using Jquery to trigger the onClick function of the grid elements upon clicking the "Computer move" button.

`$('.box[data-index="1"]').trigger('click', onUpdate)`

This code here works, but I would like to use a randomly generated number that I have stored in a variable instead. Like this below:

`$('.box[data-index=compChoice]').trigger('click', onUpdate)`

This, however, does not work. I've tried with and without quotes.

I have also tried using some different Jquery methods like .attr(), .val(), .get() in various different ways and different syntax, but I'm not having much luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my Game Board:

```
                      <div class="row">
                            <button data-index="0" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="1" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="2" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                            <button data-index="3" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="4" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="5" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                            <button data-index="6" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="7" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                            <button data-index="8" class="col-2 box alt-color"></button>
                      </div>
```

Here is my Computer Move function:

```
const onCompMove = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const compChoices = store.game.cells
  const choices = []
  for (let i = 0; i < compChoices.length; i++) {
    if (compChoices[i] === '') {
      choices.push(i)
    }
  }
  const compChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
  store.compChoice = compChoice
  console.log(compChoice)
  $('.box[data-index=compChoice]').trigger('click', onUpdate)
}

const onUpdate = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.target)
  if (store.game.over === false) {
    if ($(event.target).text() !== '') {
      return ui.invalidMove()
    } else if ($(event.target).text() === '') {
      $(event.target).text(store.turn)
    }
    const index = $(event.target).attr('data-index')
    const value = store.turn
    takenIndex.push(index)
    // console.log(takenIndex)
    api.update(index, value)
      .then(ui.onUpdateSuccess)
      .catch(ui.onUpdateFailure)
  } else {
    ui.invalidGameOver()
  }
  switchPlayer()
}
```

Comment: The second argument to `trigger` isn't a function. It's an optional data value that will be passed to the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings, you need to concatenate:

```
$('.box[data-index=' + compChoice + ']').trigger('click', onUpdate)
```

or use an ES6 template literal

```
$(`.box[data-index=${compChoice}]`).trigger('click', onUpdate)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The ES6 template literal works perfectly! Thank you so much. You are correct, the second argument was not needed. ```$(`.box[data-index=${compChoice}]`).trigger('click')```